# How do I know that all of my action method names are correct?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC controller classes I have action methods.

In my views I have `Html.ActionLink`s that have the names of those action methods set as their `actionName` values.

A typo in either of these locations will break things. Are there any tools that can check my controllers and views for validity in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [mvc futures assembly](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) there are overloads of ActionLink that take an expression e.g.:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink<ProductsController>(o => o.Create(), "New")%>
```

These can be checked at compile time and are 'refactoring friendly'.

You will need to follow a couple of extra steps to force Visual Studio to compile your views so you get an error when the names don't match up ([details here](http://webdevdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/02/aspnet-mvc-rc-compiler-post-build-step.html))

Comment: Excellent - can you provide a link?

Comment: updated the post with a link and notes on how to get the views to go through the compiler to provide compile time checking :)